# javascript for automation [open location in finder]

Tags: javascript, osascript, javascript-automation

I am trying to figure out how JXA(JavaScript for Automation) works, so try to translate a simple applescript as below to JXA.

```
tell application "Finder"
    open location "smb://XXXXXXXX"
end tell
```

what I tried is here:

```
finder = Application("Finder")
finder.open({location:"smb://xxxxxx"})
```

but I fail..., and I am new to applescript, not really understand the description in library.
and here is how the library describe the `open`

```
open (v) : Open the specified object(s)
open specifier : list of objects to open
  [using specifier] : the application file to open the object with
  [with properties record] : the initial values for the properties, to be included with the open command sent to the application that opens the direct object
```

please kindly advise how should I amend the code. ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Oh ... I got the Ans..., it's nothing about `Application("Finder")`, it is for `standardAdditions`

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.openLocation("smb://xxxxxxxx")
```

Comment: thank you, it took like 30 mins for me to find the right method name `openLocation`